# Python Discord Bot, needing the Server ID

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot in python, and to keep the data on my computer I am using a dictionary in a text file, but if I want multi-server support for something like config I need to know the server's id. The only thing I found that could've worked is `discord.Server.id` but it returns `<member 'id' of 'Server' objects>`. I was wondering if there is any other way to do this in python? My exact code is this:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def info(ctx):
    await bot.say("ID: {}".format(discord.Server.id))
```

which returns

```
ID: <member 'id' of 'Server' objects>
```

when I run c*info (c* being my bot's prefix). I don't know the cause of this error or what I'm doing wrong so please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get an instance of the `Server` class from the [command invocation context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context) `ctx`.  That object will have a meaningful `id` attribute.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def info(ctx):
    await bot.say("ID: {}".format(ctx.message.server.id))
```

For [discord.py-rewrite](/questions/tagged/discord.py-rewrite), this would be

```
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send("ID: {}".format(ctx.guild.id))
```