# How to automatically get the server id

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to automatically get the server id automatically in a message so it can automatically know which server it's in. i need this for a member count message shown in the code below

OK, just as a little background, I'm new to this type of thing and not really good at it.

my code:

````
id = client.get_guild(server id here)
    if message.content == "member count":
        await message.channel.send(f"""**Member Count**: {id.member_count}""")```
````

Comment: As I have understood you are looking for server id(IP address as it is unique) so this code will give you your server IP `import socket` `hostname = socket.gethostname()` `IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Discord Bot, needing the Server ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638400/python-discord-bot-needing-the-server-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do
in a `on_message` use `message.guild.id`

in a command `async def ping` use `ctx.guild.id`