# Get server ID in discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im trying to figure out how to get a server ID in discord rewrite so that I can save specific settings on an individual server- level basis. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Possible dup - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638537/1935238

Comment: By going to User Settings > Appearance > Developer Mode, you can put your Discord client in Developer mode, which allows you to right click on the server and select "Copy ID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're collecting context from the original message/command, then you can use `ctx.guild.name` to return the name or `ctx.guild.id` to return the ID of the guild where the command was posted.

Example:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(name='whereami', help='print the current server name/id')
async def whereami(ctx):

    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.name}, you are currently in {ctx.guild.name} ({ctx.guild.id}).')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to storage any data I recommend to you JSON files
Simply (to get server (guild in rewrite) ID:
if command:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    ID = ctx.guild.id
```

if event (e.g. on_member_join()):

```
@bot.event()
async def on_member_join(member):
    ID = member.guild.id
```

if you wanna to save that into JSON file you could:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    ID[str(ctx.guild.id)] = [content to save with specific ID]
    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(ID, f, indent=4)
```

It will `dump` a data to JSON file. In this files it will be look like:

```
{
    "[guild id]": "[content to save]",
}
```

With this method you can save as much as you want